# iOS App in background longer than 10 minutes and communicating with Web Service

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have a app using Location Updates and it can run in the background longer than 10 minutes.  This app can communicate with **Web Service A** both in the **background less than and greater than 10 minutes**.  The problem I'm facing is that it **cannot** communicate with **Web Service B** when my app is in the background **greater than 10 minutes**--I get a 500: internal server error.  I can communicate with **Web Service B** when my app is in the background less than 10 minutes.

**Note**: I can communicate with Web Service A & B in the foreground as well.  Also note that I use the same code/libraries to communicate with Web Service A & B whether they are in the foreground or background.

Has anyone experienced this same problem?  Can you please ideas for debugging?  Once my Server admin is available I will ask him to analyze the request being received and also check if the socket is being closed prematurely.

Comment: Definitely want to check with admin, as a 500 is usually a message from the server, not something internally generated.  Can you add the code you're using to make the connection? (or at least indicate what mechanism you're using)?

Comment: @gaige I'm using the LRResty library for communication with the server: '[[LRResty client] get:escapedUrlString parameters:nil headers:params  withBlock:^(LRRestyResponse *response) { // code here}'.  I'll definitely check with him when he gets online.

Answer (score 0):

> I get a 500: internal server error

This hasn't really got anything to do with iOS background services.  Your application is running and communicating with the server.

To debug this issue, hook your app up to a proxy like Charles, and look for the difference between requests that succeed and requests that fail.

I suspect your session might be timing out on the server.  Look at your server configuration to see if your timeout parameter matches up with what you are observing.

Comment: Jim:  I understand the 500 is generated server-side, I just thought it was peculiar being that my requests succeed in the background for the first 10 minutes, but not after.  Good point on Charles Proxy Jim--I'll try it out right now.  Thanks for the quick response!